# What is the visual manoeuvring area (circling approach) radius for PANS-Ops (ICAO)?

Tags: circling-approach, procedure-design, pans-ops

I'm very confused of the actual radius of the "protected area" in a circling approach for a PAN-OPS approach plate. The ICAO doc 8168 contains information for circling approach at 1 000 ft. But what about airports that are sea level? How do you calculate the radius?

P.s. Not TERPS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 300 m and 1 000 m tables you found are examples. For the actual radius for any aerodrome elevation you need to apply the formulae.

> The radius is determined using the formulas in Section 2, Chapter 3, Turn area construction (...) The TAS is based on:
>
> a) altitude: aerodrome elevation + 300 m (1 000 ft); and
> b) temperature: ISA + 15°.

First is $R$ (rate of turn) using $V$ (TAS in km/h) and $\alpha$ (bank angle of 20° for circling per Table I-2-3-1). Then plug $R$ in $r$ for the radius.

$$R = (6\;355 \tan \alpha) / \pi V
$$

$$r = V / (20 \pi R)
$$

Now, the $V$ (TAS) depends on the category and altitude (which is already aerodrome + 1 000 ft).

First get the IAS from Table I-4-1-1, then convert the IAS to TAS using the conversion factor in Section 2, Appendix to Chapter 1 (I-2-1-App-1).